# Measuring ohms on 200 scale

Tags: resistance, conversion

I hope this is on the correct form.

I’m measuring the resistance of a stator. The shop manual says I should get a reading of between 5.7 and 8.0 on an ohm scale of Rx1000.

The meter I have has scales of 200 and 2000. I set it on 2000 and got a reading of 1200. How does this compare to the shop manual expecting?

Also in relation, could you show me the calculation?

Edit: ok. So I did some more reading. I guess I completely misunderstood the 1000 vs 2000 scale. Although I still don’t grasp the “2” range idea, am I right to understand that the manual is saying to use the 1000 (because it is expecting an analog meter) and getting result of 5.7 is the same as using a DMM in the 2000 range and getting a result of 5.7?

I think my reading of 1200 was incorrect. I’ll need to do it again.

Comment: `could you show me the calculation?` ... calculation of what?

Comment: does the shop manual expect an analog ohmmeter to be used?

Comment: If the reading is steady it should be accurate with this low constant current. Try a DMM for a second opinion then decide if your windings are shorted.

Comment: @jsotola I figure if the scale I’m using is 2000 and manual is saying to use 1000, I need to convert/calculate what my reading on the 2000 scale is at 1000 (I thought dividing it by 2 might work, but then my reading would way out of spec….which maybe true. Regarding your second comment, yes, the manual was expecting an analog meter.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thanks for your input. I’m using a DMM for my reading.

Comment: Can you _edit your question_ with pictures of the relevant manual page, and of your meter -- best would be of your meter while you're measuring the stator resistance, if you have enough hands.

Comment: Your DMM should read ohms directly, then.  5.7 on a "Rx1000" scale means 5.7k-ohms; 8.0 on a "Rx1000" scale means 8k-ohms.  You want to put the meter on the **20k** scale, but it sounds like you have some shorted turns.

Comment: @Oldoldhouseguy the 2000 is the maximum reading that the digital ohmmeter can display (actually 1999)... that is because the leading seven segment digit is a `1`, not an `8` ... with all segments lit, the display shows `1888` (cheaper than `8888`) .... the reading of 1200 is 1200 ohms ... an analog meter has a pointer that moves between `0` and `10` ... a reading of `5.7`, with a ×1000  multiplier is equal to 5700 ohms

Comment: an analogue multimeter is much worse than that on the ohms scale: the needle goes from infinity to zero.

Answer (score 1):

> I’m measuring the resistance of a stator. The shop manual says I should get a reading of between 5.7 and 8.0 on an ohm scale of Rx1000.

"Rx" scales are for analogue meters where you have to read the scale and then multiply the result, I'm guessing that manual means that the stator resistance should be  between 5700 and 8000 ohms. which seems about right for a small synchronous motor like a microwave oven turntable disco ball, or mechanical timer.

so for a digital multimeter you need to set it to the range larger than the expected resistance, so set it 20K and expect a reading between 5.70 and 8.00

I measured a motor that I have here with my cheap digital meter and got `10.00` on the 20K scale (meaning 10000 ohms, not that I trust it past the second digit)
[image]

There's no need for re-scaling except for the gross re-scaling of 10 to 10000,

if had instead used the 200K scale (0 to 20000) it would have displayed  `10.0` (and I would still need to multiply by 1000)

If you're seeing 1200 on the 2K scale that's actually 1200 and you want more than 5000 so something's wrong.